# Sliding doors HTML buttons in Safari Win

Tags: css, safari

I have the following HTML for buttons implementing sliding doors technique that look fine in everything but Safari on Windows:

```
<button type="submit">
    <span>Button</span>
</button>
```

This is the corresponding CSS:

```
button {
    background:url("../images/sprBgBtn.png") no-repeat right -47px;
    border:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:27px;
    line-height:27px;   
    overflow:visible;
    padding:0 26px 0 0;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    width:auto;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;  /* overrides extra padding in Firefox */
    padding:0;
}

button span {
    background:url("../images/sprBgBtn.png") no-repeat left top;
    display:block;
    height:27px;
    line-height:27px;
    padding:0 0 0 26px;
    position:relative;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

If i omit the following code then the same issue will appear in FFOX:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;  /* overrides extra padding in Firefox */
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears a reduction in right padding for Chrome and Safari solves the issue:

```
/* Safari and Google Chrome only - fix margins */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #icis_dashboard .submit_btn,
    #colorbox .submit_btn 
    {
        padding:0 23px 0 0;       
        }  

    #icis_dashboard .submit_btn span,
    #colorbox .submit_btn span {
        margin-top: -1px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that button, being an inline element by default (unless you overrode its display property somewhere else in code that's not here), probably doesn't like the inner span being set to block, thus unexpected behavior on safari windows (and i'd assume other webkit browsers unless there's something particularly special abt the windows version of safari over the mac version or over google chrome).

Comment: A button is only an inline element when used inside another inline element which is not the case here.

Comment: ok. do you happen to know if this happens in another webkit browser like chrome? if it doesn't, maybe there's a fix incorporated into a version of webkit newer than the one built into your particular version of safari?

Answer (score 0):

This too happens for me on Safari Win 5.0.3. Doesn't happen on Safari Mac 5.0.3 or Chrome Win/Mac 8+.

Because it only doesn't work on Safari Windows I'm at a loss as to how to "hack it" using negative margins...